# According to LDS (Mormon) teaching, who was the first God who began the eternal progression?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds

I understand that the LDS church teaches the concept of eternal progression, that "As God is, so man can become and as man is, so God once was."  So, men may attain godhood in exaltation.

By implication, God the Father was once a man Himself on another planet where there was another god and attained to godhood Himself through his life on that planet.

So, my question is, according to LDS teaching, who was the first God who began all this--the uncreated God, since all other gods, including God the Father would have been born spiritually through a spiritual union between the god of the previous planet and one of his wives.

Also, is there any worship given in the LDS Church to this first God?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mormon doctrine states that creation [has always been in existence](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/according-to-the-mormon-doctrines-who-created-the-universe).  As such, we can't presume that there was a beginning.

Because of this, there wasn't a *first* God, but an endless succession prior to the one true God.

Brigham Young once stated:

> How many Gods there are, I do not know. But there never was a time when there were not Gods...
> Brigham Young *(Journal of Discourses 7:333)*

Furthermore, LDS Apostle Orson Pratt stated:

> We were begotten by our Father in Heaven; the person of our Father in Heaven was begotten on a previous heavenly world by His Father; and again, He was begotten by a still more ancient Father, and so one, from one generation to generation
> LDS Apostle Orson Pratt *(The Seer, pg. 132)*

(It should be noted that the Orson Pratt writings were later discounted by the LDS church and shouldn't be taken as doctrine.  Still, it elucidates the point.)

#### Summary

Essentially, since there was no beginning, there was no "first".  Therefore, there was no "first God" in regards to the eternal progression.  The universe, being eternal, has always been around.  The progression of Gods has likewise been eternal.

Comment: To clarify: this is not Mormon doctrine, but speculation by Mormon leaders.

Comment: Though, "[God's] course is one eternal round" [refs](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/search?lang=eng&type=verse&query=one+eternal+round) lends credence to those theories.

Comment: This belief is also suggested by the LDS Church hymn [If You Could Hie to Kolob](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/if-you-could-hie-to-kolob). "Do you think that you could ever,
Through all eternity,
Find out the generation
Where Gods began to be?"

Answer (score 1):

I am a member of the church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints.(Mormon) We are taught that there is no beginning and there is no end. We have always existed.

In 1833 the Lord revealed to the Prophet Joseph Smith that

> 29 Man was also in the beginning with God. Intelligence, or the light of truth, was not created or made, neither indeed can be. ([D&C 93:29](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/93.29?lang=eng#29?lang=eng)).

Several years later, with the publication of the book of Abraham, additional information about the immortality of the soul of man came to light. The Lord told Abraham that these intelligences or spirits

> ...have no beginning; they existed before, they shall have no end, they shall exist after, for they are gnolaum, or eternal. ([Abraham 3:18](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/abr/3.18?lang=eng#18?lang=eng)).

The Prophet Joseph often suggested that just as the earth could not be created out of nothing, neither could man. In the [King Follett Discourse](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1971/05/the-king-follett-sermon?lang=eng), the Prophet Joseph once again addressed this subject of the immortality of the spirit of man.

> The soul—the mind of man—the immortal spirit.  Where did it come from? All learned men and doctors of divinity say that God created it in the beginning; but it is not so: the very idea lessens man in my estimation . . .

> The mind or the intelligence which man possesses is co-equal [co-eternal] with God himself . . .
> Is it logical to say that the intelligence of spirits is immortal, and yet that it had a beginning? The intelligence of spirits had no beginning, neither will it have an end . . .
> Intelligence is eternal and exists upon a self-existent principle. It is a spirit from age to age, and there is no creation about it.

Comment: Hello Jasmine.  Wall of Text is not a suitable format for SE Q&A sites.  I broke up the wall a bit, and pulled your quotes from the scriptures into quote blocks.  It appears to me that the entire part that begins.  *The soul - the mind of man - the immortal spirit*  is a quotation from the Prophet Joseph Smith's discourse.  Is that correct? If so, we need to enclose it into quote blocks.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to get the most out of an SE site.  Welcome!

Comment: An official source for the King Follett discourse is https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1971/05/the-king-follett-sermon?lang=eng

Answer (score 0):

Within your question you stated:  "By implication, God the Father was once a man Himself on another planet where there was another god and attained to godhood Himself through his life on that planet."  Only canonized LDS scripture is true Mormon doctrine, all the rest is pure speculation, including your "By implication" that there was another god over God the Father. 
There is no LDS canonized scripture that indicates that there was a God before our God the Father!  In fact I think that the Book of Abraham talks of God the Father as the first and and only true God.  Abraham 3:19