# How does LDS interpret Colossians 1:16?

Tags: lds, creation, colossians, eternity

From this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90067/are-any-of-the-lds-gods-without-beginning-or-end-or-are-they-all-created-at-a-c/90070?noredirect=1#comment252210_90070) I gather that LDS teaches that all beings are eternal and that by eternal it is not meant existing timelessly beginning at some point but, rather, not actually having any starting point.  Indeed the answer asserts that the first "stage" in the existence of every person (and also every God) is that of "intelligences".  An intelligence then becomes a spirit being (the manner of this transformation is unrevealed) and a spirit being is embodied in flesh at mortal birth, lives on after mortal death, and has the opportunity to be exalted to Godhood.

The "intelligence" is asserted to be uncreated and self-existent.

This [related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/lds-doctrine-on-intelligences-having-always-existed-vs-gods-whose-godship) indicates that the LDS view of the Genesis account is that God did not create matter in the beginning but, rather, organized already existing matter.  I have not ascertained if this pre-existing matter is self-existent.  It is clear, however, that LDS teaches it was not created ... at least not by the God of Genesis.

Given that LDS teaches that all beings are self-existent (not created) and that matter was not created (at least not by the God revealed in Scripture), how does LDS interpret Colossians 1:16 which appears to clearly state that there is not anything anywhere that the God of Genesis did not create?

> For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him Colossians 1:16

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do Latter-day Saints respond to William Lane Craig's philosophical objections to the Mormon view of creation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84051/50422)

Comment: also related: [The Mormon Church teaches that Jesus Christ created under the direction of Heavenly Father and He did not create the world "out of nothing."](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83413/22319)

Comment: Could you clarify most of that? Almost every phrase in that exposition seems to require either definition, or prior knowledge, but you’re using ordinary English.

Most obviously, is LDS to be taken for Latter Day Saints, or what? More usefully, how can you consign eternal existence to such vagaries as “existing timelessly beginning at some point but, rather, not actually having any starting point”?

Does “all beings” actually mean “all people” or what? Don’t you think even to follow half of that text  really requires volumes of explanation?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you can look at the tags to get some of the meanings. CSE can't necessarily expound every term and phrase as that would rapidly enlarge every question. There have also been other recent questions that went into some of the terminology

Answer (score 3):

"Create" is understood in the sense that the word is used in virtually all non-theological discussions--"create" means to organize. In the process, the creation is often imbued with attributes it did not previously have.

**Beliefs on Creation ex Nihilo in General**

One of the most direct discussions of creation ex-nihilo comes from Joseph Smith's King Follett discourse:

> You ask the learned doctors why they say the world was made out of
> nothing, and they will answer, “Doesn’t the Bible say he created the
> world?” And they infer, from the word create, that it must have been
> made out of nothing. Now, the word create came from the word baurau,
> which does not mean to create out of nothing; it means to organize;
> the same as a man would organize materials and build a ship. Hence we
> infer that God had materials to organize the world out of
> chaos—chaotic matter, which is element, and in which dwells all the
> glory. Element had an existence from the time He had. The pure
> principles of element are principles which can never be destroyed;
> they may be organized and re-organized, but not destroyed. They had no
> beginning and can have no end. ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1971/04/the-king-follett-sermon?lang=eng))

--

**The specific passage**

A parallel argument can be made with respect to the Greek word , employed in Colossians 1:16. This verb is used to describe God's creation of both the earth & humans, and means "to create", "to build", "to form", or "to shape" ([source](https://biblehub.com/greek/2936.htm)). "Forming" & "shaping" are unambiguously not acts of creation ex nihilo, but involve working with existing materials.

As such, even if κτίζω meant creation out of nothing in some circumstance, it cannot be taken to always carry that meaning. I submit that there is no unambiguous usage of κτίζω to mean "creation out of nothing" in the New Testament (which is why the early Christian writers who supported creation ex-nihilo used 2 Maccabees, not the New Testament, as a proof text--see section 5.1 [here](https://www.fairlatterdaysaints.org/archive/publications/reviews-of-the-new-mormon-challenge/the-doctrine-of-creation-ex-nihilo-was-created-out-of-nothing)). There are, on the other hand, examples in the New Testament where κτίζω clearly means to create out of something that already exists:

- Ephesians 2:15
- 1 Cor 11:9
- Ephesians 4:24
- Matthew 19:4 (critical text)

In particular, compare 1 Cor 11:9 & Matthew 19:4 to the description of those events in Genesis 2:7,22. God created (κτίζω per 1 Cor, Matthew) out of things/entities that already existed.

---

**Appendix**

Additional relevant scriptural statements include:

> Man was also in the beginning with God. Intelligence, or the light of
> truth, was not created or made, neither indeed can be. (Doctrine &
> Covenants 93:29)

> The elements are eternal (Doctrine & Covenants 93:33)

Note this does not say that the body or the spirit has existed from eternity past, but that the "intelligence" (or "self" or "inner person") has always existed.

For a more in-depth discussion of philosophy, physics, and history regarding creation ex-nihilo, see my answer [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84089/51818).

Comment: "Now, the word create came from the word baurau, which does not mean to create out of nothing; it means to organize"  This is incorrect.  Create comes from *κτιζω (ktizo)* in Colossians and means to come into being because of the will of a founder.

Comment: Also, "made" in Matthew 19 is *ποιεω (poieo)* not *κτιζω (ktizo)* as you say.

Comment: @MikeBorden the Joseph Smith quote is not a commentary on the Colossians passage, but outlines the LDS view of creation ex nihilo. The verb κτίζω is indeed found in Matt 19:4. Note that in English "made"/"created" shows up twice. You are referring to the 2nd instance, I am referring to the first, which is κτίζω

Comment: Must be a different manuscript.  KJV has *ποιεω* in both places.  I understand Smith was commenting on a Hebrew word but his point can't stand in the face of Colossians where the word used does not mean "to organize" but "to be willed into existence".

Comment: @MikeBorden I looked it up--looks like the Textus Receptus has  ποιεω and the critical text has κτίζω. I updated my answer, added a few more relevant passages, and provided further response per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the Greek [lexicon](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g2936/kjv/tr/0-1/) for the word create:

> κτίζω (ktizō)

> Root Word (Etymology): Probably akin to κτάομαι ([G2932](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g2932/kjv/tr/0-1/)) (through the idea of proprietor-ship of the manufacturer)

> Outline of Biblical Usage:
>
> - to make habitable, to people, a place, region, island
>
>   - to found a city, colony, state
> - to create
>
>   - of God creating the worlds
>   - to form, shape, i.e. to completely change or transform

> Strong’s Definitions: κτίζω ktízō, ktid'-zo; probably akin to G2932 (through the idea of proprietorship of the manufacturer); to fabricate, i.e. found (form originally):—create, Creator, make.

One can see a similarity to this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83423/22319), in that this verse  indicate not creation *ex nihilo* but making a place habitable, founding, forming, or shaping with pre-existing material/matter.

> For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him [Colossians 1:16](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/col/1.15-17?lang=eng#15)

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day saints do believe that God organized/[created](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/creation?lang=eng) the heaven, earth, visible and invisible. With the understanding that he formed matter into what we have today. Even though we don't believe he created the matter, he formed everything and so he is regarded as the Creator. (if someone builds a home for you, they are the creator even if they didn't personally create/gather the materials-God could also be considered the architect as all things were [created spiritually first](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/doctrines-of-the-gospel-student-manual/7-creation?lang=eng#p2))

From unofficial [apologist](https://www.fairlatterdaysaints.org/answers/Question:_Does_Colossians_1:16_teach_that_Jesus_created_all_things_out_of_nothing?) site (wording is clear and concise):

> Thus, Jesus certainly participated in the creation of all created things—but He worked with preexisting chaotic materials. The angelic ranks of "thrones, dominions, principalities, and powers" were also created by Christ, for these beings did not assume their angelic status or form without divine creative power, even though some aspect of their "intelligence" pre-dated God's creative acts in their behalf.

Comment: And these preexisting chaotic materials are uncreated?  Self-existent?  Created by someone or something else?

Comment: @MikeBorden uncreated matter/materials [source](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/doctrines-of-the-gospel-student-manual/7-creation#p22)

Comment: Spirit trees?  Spirit amoeba?  God had a beginning and these did not?

Comment: @MikeBorden see this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/90070/22319) about beginning. I don't understand you question about trees/amoeba

Comment: The paragraph bullet point preceding the content you linked to in yesterday's comment spoke of spirit beasts, spirit fish, spirit trees, spirit amoeba, etc. ((Bruce R. McConkie, The Millennial Messiah, 642–43).

Comment: @MikeBorden yes all things were created spiritually first before being placed on the earth. [Millenial Messiah](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL4273313M/The_millennial_Messiah) or same topic, easier access [spirit creation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/gs/spirit-creation?lang=eng)

Comment: The spiritual is not first according to 1 Cor. 15:42-49.  We are told in Genesis that every plant and herb had not yet "grown in the earth" **because** it had not yet rained...much like how a seed can actually be there but waits for moisture to germinate.  There is nothing there to indicate that first there was a spirit tree.  Nonetheless the LDS view puts trees, beasts, and amoeba on the same footing as Almighty God since all have begun as uncreated somethings (whether pre existing chaotic material or Intelligences) which become spirit somethings and then temporal somethings, etc.

Comment: @MikeBorden 1 Cor 15 aren't about the spirit creation, those verses are about the resurrection (which I have no issue with). spirit and physical are different. I view spirit form as a template/blueprint, so everything/everyone has a blueprint (this isn't a whole picture-I don't think this is explicitly stated anywhere), and once given physical form we grow into that blueprint. there is nothing to indicate there isn't. Gen 2:5 indicates `And every plant of the field before it was in the earth,...` so plants existed before they were in the earth

Comment: Sounds like Platonic forms.  God Himself was once only a blueprint/template, right?  As we are, God once was?  Template God...template amoeba.    No rain and no man to work the ground **are given as the reason** nothing was yet growing *in the earth*.  It does not say they weren't there because they were still just blueprints.  It doesn't say they weren't blueprints, I guess, but it does give an actual reason other than blueprints.

Comment: @MikeBorden if you want to think of it like that sure, but its not a theory/idea. As noted in the other answer I commented, and noted other places spirit is matter. Template isn't the best word (I used in trying to convey the concept, but you won't see template used in LDS doctrine to explain this, that I know of). Here is one reason why additional scripture is useful, as it can explain that things were created spiritually first, as it isn't clearly stated in Bible

Comment: Other "scriptures" often contradict the Scriptures we have.  "Ye are my witnesses, saith the LORD, and my servant whom I have chosen: that ye may know and believe me, and understand that I am he: **before me there was no God formed, neither shall there be after me.** - Isaiah 43:10".   "Formed" here is to fashion into shape like a potter or to pre-ordain:  To "organize" if you will.  This lines up with the LDS view of creation and plainly says that there only ever was, is, or will be one God.

Comment: @MikeBorden [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54772/22319)

Comment: I saw that.  The idol "gods" that God wants Israel to keep away from are actually no God at all.  That is the point, there is only one God and everything else that is called God is false. (Isaiah 44).   The pride of a city to say there is no other city is not a statement of truth, it is a lie of pride and God's declaration that He alone is God is not such.  That part of your answer compares apples to non-apples.

Comment: @MikeBorden I addressed the verse in question here. I addressed Isaiah 43 there. You are free to not accept it, but that is the LDS perspective, as was asked. If you have further questions post them in a new question. Its kind of obvious none of my answers/comments are satisfactory to you